# Evaluating a formula as the denominator goes to $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came across a theroem which says that if $S=(ar^{n-1}-a)/(r-1)$ when $r \neq 1$
then $S=(n+1)a$ if $r=1$.
But for $r=1$ the above equation isn't well-defined. How do they come to this result?

Comment: Have a look at De l'Hôpital's Theorem.

Comment: It should be $S=(n-1)a,$ or $S=(ar^{n+1}-a)/(r-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is the formula for a geometric progression. When $r\neq 1$, the sequence is $a,ar,ar^2,...$ so that the sum of the first $n$ terms is $\frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$. When $r=1$, the sequence is $a,a,a,...$ so that the sum of the first $n$ terms is $na$.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful: we understand what you mean, but you wrote a rather arbitrary thing. What is true is that
$$
\lim_{r \to 1} \frac{ar^{n+1}-a}{r-1}=(n+1)a, \tag{1}
$$
but $S$ is *undefined* at $r=1$. The limit (1) is simply $a$ times the derivative of $r \mapsto r^{n+1}$ at $r=1$.

Comment: using l'Hopital's Rule proofs this easily

Comment: @F'OlaYinka ... but you need a different proof of the formula $\frac{d}{dr}r^{n+1}=(n+1)r^n$ :-)

Comment: it's a polynomial function, very obvious